# How to determine the order of function calls in a logic expression

Tags: c

I'm confused about the order of function calls. I have list the orders I have tried，but still got wrong answer.

## !!!The answer is "i and j value are undefined."

#### According to operator precedence：

> 1. if compiler calculates the values from left to right

```
   int i = (1+0) || (ignored);  //1  
   int j = (1) || (ignored);   //1
```

> 2. if compiler firstly calculates the value after '+', calculates other values from left to right

```
   int i = (0+0) || (1);  //1  
   int j = (2) || (ignored);   //1
```

I still get wrong conclusion.

#### So I try to disobey operator precedence

> 3. if compiler first calculates the values from right to left

```
   int i = (1+1) || (0);  //1
   int j = (ignored) || (2+2);  //1
```

> 4. if compiler only first calculates the value before '+', calculates other values from right to left

```
   int i = (0+1) || (0);  //1  
   int j = (ignored) || (1+2);    //1
```

I still get wrong conclusion.

#### I guess again that compiler may not ignore the expression after || even if left is true

> 5. if compiler calculates the values from left to right

```
   int i = (1+0) || (1);    //1
   int j = (2) || (2+3);    //1
```

> 6. if compiler firstly calculates the value after '+', calculates other values from left to right

```
   int i = (0+0) || (1);    //1
   int j = (2) || (3+3);    //1
```

> 7. if compiler first calculates the values from right to left

```
   int i = (1+1) || (0);  //1
   int j = (3) || (2+2);  //1
```

> 8. if compiler only first calculates the value before '+', calculates other values from right to left

```
   int i = (0+1) || (0);  //1
   int j = (3) || (1+2);  //1
```

I still get wrong conclusion.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int x = 0;
int f(){
  if(x == 0) return x + 1;
  else return x - 1;
}
int g(){
  return x++;
}
int main(){
  int i = (f() + g()) || g();
  int j = g() || (f() + g());
}
```

Regardless of the order, I except i=1 and j value is 1.
But answer is that i and j value are undefined.
I wonder which case results in another output...
forgive my foolishness.......

Comment: You might like to read about "[Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)"

Comment: I've already considered that.

Comment: what makes you think that these values are undefined?

Comment: "But answer is that i and j value are undefined." Where did you get this answer?

Comment: I think they are defined, but our exam's answer is that "i and j value are undefined."

Comment: "I guess again that compiler may not ignore the expression after || even if left is true" Nope. In that case the compiler MUST ignore the part after `||`

Comment: but for other cases ,  I can't get any counterexample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyse `i`. Note that the second argument of `||` is *only* evaluated if the left hand argument is 0.

`i` is always 1 even if the approach by which this result is attained is *unspecified*.

There's no undefined behaviour here. (Formally this is due to the fact that a function call is a *sequenced step*.)

The language does not *specify* the order in which `f()` and `g()` are called in the evaluation of the left hand side. That is left to the implementation. Formally it is **not** even *implementation defined* since an implementation is not required to document the behaviour. If `f()` is called first then the value of `f() + g()` is non-zero. If `g()` is called first then `f() + g()` is zero, so `g()` is called again, and that is also non-zero as `x` is 1 at that point.

`j` drops out trivially as 1 since only the left hand side of `||` is evaluated.

A more interesting variant would be

```
int f(){
  if(x == 0) return ++x;
  else return --x;
}
```

where actually different implementations could return 0 or 1 for `i` or `j`.

Comment: actually ....the situation you mentioned is the case 1 and case 2 I listed above....

Comment: If g() is called first then f() + g() is zero. As g() is invoked once. The global variable x becomes 1. So when g() is called again, g return 1. That means “int i = (0+0) || (1);”

Comment: @Esual: Oops you are correct. A couple of minor edits on the answer.

Comment: That's where I feel desperate.

Comment: @Esual: You can't assume that your examiners are perfect. Your job is to point this out (constructively) to them. I believe my answer is correct. Let's see how the community reacts to it.

Comment: Thank you, tomorrow I will ask my examiners for correction.

Comment: @Esual I think this is a more concise answer than mine, but I'm leaving mine down there in case you want to do a step-by-step walkthrough with your examiners.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb and claim that the exam's answer is wrong.

Starting with the first expression to be evaluated,

```
f() + g()
```

The ordering of the function calls is unspecified but they can't be interleaved, so there are two cases;

1. `f()`, then `g()`
   `f()` returns `0 + 1` which is 1, then `g()` returns the value of `x`, which is 0, and increments `x`.
   The result is 1, which gets converted to `true`.
2. `g()`, then `f()`
   `g()` returns 0 and increments `x`, then `f()` returns `x - 1` (because `x` is 1 now), which is 0.
   This result is 0, which is `false`.

`x` is incremented to 1 in both cases.

In case 1, evaluation stops, `i` is 1, and `x` is 1.

In case 2, evaluation continues with `g()`, which returns 1 and increments `x` to 2.

Thus, regardless of the evaluation order, `i` is 1.
`x`, on the other hand, may be either 1 or 2.

For `j`, you have `g()` first, which returns either 1 or 2.

Since both 1 and 2 are truthy, `j` must be 1.

Comment: Yes I agree with this too. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence and evaluation order are not the same thing.

For most operators, C makes no assumption in which order their arguments are evaluated. A compiler may even have different strategies during the same compilation, depending, e.g, on optimization opportunities.

The only operators that have a predefined ordering are those were there is a logical dependency from the left operannd to the right operand(s), e.g `||`, `&&`, `?:` and `,`.

And if your are refering to the code at the end of your question, the answer is not "undefined" but "unspecified".

Comment: I have discussed many cases, but found that whatever evaluation order is, the answer is same: " i=1 and j=1."

Comment: I have run the code by many compilers, and each time I use printf("%d,%d\n",i,j),stdout is "1,1\n"

Comment: @Esual, that is not a good argument. The only thing that helps is to systematically write down all possible orderings of operations.

Comment: I use stackoverflow for the first, so I can't upload picture of my exam paper. It's also because I'm not good at c grammar...